# Hello! Is it possible to make content in CiviCRM and publish it directly to Facebook?

Tags: extension, facebook

Is it possible to make content in CiviCRM and publish it directly to Facebook?  For example, uploading the video and posting a link that's leading to an article, or official website?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'content'. Normally 'content' would be driven from the CMS that civi is wired in to, ie Drupal, WPress, Joomla or Backdrop

Comment: Please forgive my lack of knowledge, since this is the first time I am trying to use CiviCRM. Our NGO decided to move the official webpage from umbraco to Wordpress and they are interested in CiviCRM, so it is up to me to figure out all the details. They are wondering if there's a possibility of making posts like articles, videos and links (that we usually see on FB) in CiviCRM and posting them to our official FB page. What is the correct procedure? 
Thank you for your time!

Comment: CiviCRM is designed for managing contacts, memberships, donations etc. Articles and videos sound like a job for WordPress.

Comment: Perhaps to explain, civicrm should be wired in to your wordpress site so they work as a single system in some respects.